# WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil class methods are giving UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, liferay

I'm trying to signal a `workflowInstance` to goto the next state of the kaleo workflow single-approve-workflow definition.
So Now when I try to call any method of the `WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil` class, then its giving `UnsupportedOperationException`. 
And any method of the `WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil` class methods are internally calling `WorkflowInstanceManagerProxyBean` methods and which has empty implementation and 
and I'm able to see all the methods are by default throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` itself.

1. So I guess I'm missing something here to create its sub-class objects. So please let me know if something is missed out before calling `WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil` class methods.
2. And also kaleo classes are not available in my application but those are available in DB
   For eg: kaleoinstance table is available in Database but `KaleoInstance` class is not available in my application. I guess that kaleo workflow app is deployed separately by downloading the app from purchases window of market place.

**Olaf:** I'm deploying my portelt wars directly by creating wars which is generated by ant "war" command of liferay sdk plugin.

and here is my code to transit from one state to another state

First time the kaleo workflow will be started using this code

```
WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance(
    sheet.getCompanyId(), sheet.getGroupId(), sheet.getUserId(),
    sheet.class.getName(), sheet.getsheetId(), sheet,
    serviceContext);
```

and from next time onwards the state should be transited using the below method

```
public void transitState(Sheet sheet, String state, ServiceContext serviceContext) 
        throws com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException, 
        com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException {
    Map<String, Serializable> workflowContext= new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
    workflowContext.put(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_USER_ID, sheet.getUserId());
    workflowContext.put(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_CLASS_PK, sheet.getSheetId());
    workflowContext.put("serviceContext", serviceContext);
    WorkflowInstanceLink workflowInstanceLink = WorkflowInstanceLinkLocalServiceUtil.getWorkflowInstanceLink(sheet.getCompanyId(), sheet.getGroupId(), sheet.class.getName(), sheet.getSheetId());
    WorkflowInstance workflowInstance=WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil.getWorkflowInstance(sheet.getCompanyId(),workflowInstanceLink.getWorkflowInstanceId());
    WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil.signalWorkflowInstance(sheet.getCompanyId(), sheet.getUserId(), workflowInstanceLink.getWorkflowInstanceId(), state, workflowInstance.getWorkflowContext());
}
```

Comment: Please add more information: What version are you running? Did you deploy kaleo-web (find it in tomcat/webapps/kaleo-web)? How do you deploy the code that experiences this exception? You won't need the implementation (KaleoInstance) in your application - Liferay proxies around the necessity to have the implementation available. If it doesn't, *it* might not have access to the implementation (e.g. kaleo not deployed) or you're calling from random code, that's not been properly initialized.

Comment: Hi Olaf Kock, Thanks for the reply,
I'm using liferay 6.1 CE
and kaleo-web is installed in my tomcat and i'm able to see that folder in webapps folder.
So what is the permission issue here?  Where should I give permissions? Should there be any extra permissions provided in liferay web tool? or you are saying just about the folder permissions?

I'm experiencing this exception when I call any method of WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil class from my service class.

My requirement is to call 
WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil.signalWorkflowInstance(args...) method to transit from one state to another state

Comment: Could someone please answer my question please...

Comment: Show some code. If nobody answers here this often is because there's not enough information in the question. And answer all my questions from above, e.g. how do you deploy your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was completely my bad. kaleo was not deployed properly in my local. kaleo-web module was there in tomcat/webapps but I don't know how that was installed automatically and I didn't find any dependency in my project to add that kaleo-web module into my project. But somehow that folder was there in my webapps folder. 
So I just removed that old one and re-installed from apps-store tab of my application so now its working fine.

Thanks Olaf.